# Error from the opening of visual studio 2019 with unreal engine 5. E0070 incomplete type is not allowed

Tags: visual-studio-2019, unreal-engine5

So I've just created a project in unreal engine and just searched through files in visual studio(changed nothing). When I tried to build my project, it returned [those errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BOYw.png). Have no idea what's going on...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question.